# Behavior of $1+x^2\sin^2x$

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to see whether or not certain integral is convergent.

Can I assume that $1+x^2\sin^2x$ behaves as $x^2\sin^2x$ as $x\to\infty$?

I'm not sure because of the $\sin$ function.

Comment: No you cannot because it's not true the behavior will be consistently dominated by that term. However more simply you do know that $$1+x^2\sin^2x \geq 1$$

Comment: What about $ f(n\pi)$ you will never walk alone.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(x)=1+g(x)$$

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\infty$, then

$f(x)=g(x)(1+\epsilon(x))$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty}\epsilon(x)=0$.

In this case we have
$$f(x)\sim g(x)\;\;(x\to\infty)$$

Now, you have $ g(x)=x^2\sin^2(x)$.

$$g(n\pi)=0 \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}g(n\pi)=0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}g(\frac \pi 2+n\pi)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

thus $$\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)\ne \infty$$

we cannot, nor write $ f(x) $ as

$$f(x)=x^2\sin^2(x)\Bigl(1+\epsilon(x)\Bigr)\;\;(x\to\infty)$$

neither that
$$f(x)\sim x^2\sin^2(x)\;\; (x\to\infty)$$